# MySQL NDB Cluster and Master Master replication

Tags: replication, database-replication, master-slave, mysql-cluster

I'm asking this to see whether I'm doing the things are correctly or to get advise what needs to be done.

Thing is I'm trying to run both NDB clustering and Master Master replication to same database.
[image: Following is the Application architecture]

In here What I'm trying to do is create a db and run both clustering and master master replication in same database.

> As eg : I create db called my_db_1 and create user table which has the engine NDBCluster and also
>   create a table data_log and change its engine in to INNODB. Put both
>   master master configuration and ndb configuration in to my.cnf.
>
> Except this I added replicate_do_table=data_log in my.cnf too.

What I need to know is, is this setup ok to run in production and what issues will be occurred, having this kind of architecture for the system.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want some parts of your data in NDB
and a data log in InnoDB. One thing to remember here is that InnoDB
doesn't support Multi-master. So you have to make sure that any updates
of the data_log table is directed to the correct MySQL server.

I think with Group replication it is technically possible to run with
Multi-master for Inno